# Acceso a archivos en carpeta OneDrive

Tags: c#, .net

Esto desarrollando una aplicación en .Net que requiere el acceso a archivos en ofimática (Word, Excel, PDF, etc.) alojados en carpetas de OneDrive, el acceso debe ser nivel de stream y no lógico, ya que se desea agregar una firma electrónica a dichos documentos, luego de agregrada la firma ese mismo documento se almacene en otra carpeta en la misma cuenta de OneDrive.

Parte del código que se utiliza para firma en PDF es el siguiente:

```
Stream archivoPdf = new FileStream(pdfCon, FileMode.Create);
PdfReader firmapdf = new PdfReader(pdfSin);
PdfStamper fir = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(firmapdf, archivoPdf, '\0');
```

Solo he podido avanzar obteniedo la ruta lógica, usando un ejemplo de la API de OneDrive con JavaScript.

```
"size": 17358,
  "webUrl": "https://1drv.ms/x/s!AEuukj7rjH7VjH8",
  "file": {
    "hashes": {
      "crc32Hash": "E248ECFD",
      "sha1Hash": "673102CFAAF6B3C13DAC3E850FE51B0DA8834104"
    },
    "mimeType": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
  },
  "fileSystemInfo": {
    "createdDateTime": "2015-03-12T13:45:04.52Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2015-03-12T13:21:08Z"
  },
  "children@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('xxxxxxxxx%40hotmail.com')/drive/root/children",
  "children": [],
```

Answer (score 0):

Si los archivos de OneDrive estan en local, con acceder a la carpeta donde estan sincronizados el acceso es igual que cualquier otra carpeta.

Otra opción es la clase FileOpenPicket:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207847

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker#examples